# Question about applescript and expose

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, applescript

Using applescript, how can I get the "preview" of a window of an application? By preview I mean the preview window you see when you use expose on your mac. How can I get those video feeds using applescript, or if not applescript using cocoa framework?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it from AppleScript, but you can do it from C.  See the [Quartz Window Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CGWindow_Reference/Reference/Functions.html) functions and the [Son of Grab](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SonOfGrab/) example.